# Error while running unrar on docker ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, unrar

I have installed unrar, my script was running fine when i deployed it on ubuntu (not inside docker). After implementing the same script, i'm getting this error. I've the unrar command is executing, but its showing failed for all files without any other error message.

[image]

What to do?

Comment: Can you try with unrar x -vp sample.rar?

Comment: just tried, same result

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working, installed some other libraries and unrar started working properly.

```
RUN apt-get install -y unace unrar zip unzip p7zip-full p7zip-rar sharutils rar
```

Note: All of them might not be needed, I'm in a rush, so, couldn't test exactly which library was needed.